# autoconfir rmdir

Tags: octave, rmdir

i am running a long matlab script and it should run when i am not around.
part of the script cleans up previous created folder structures (temp data).

```
rmdir('dir','s');
```

however matlabs `rmdir` will ask me the following:

```
remove entire contents of dir? (yes or now)
```

and i need to supply either `yes` or `no` to proceed.

i tried piping

```
pipe(printf('yes'),rmdir('dir','s'));
```

and other things but nothing works so far.

**Problem**

how do i autoconfirm with 'yes' to 'rmdir' so my script will not get stopped because of this issue?m

Comment: It doesn't ask anything to me (version R2010b on Windows Vista)

Comment: Are you using octave and not Matlab? There en- or disabling this question is a feature which can be controlled.

Comment: If you are working on Linux, you can use Matlab's `system` function to issue an OS command, such as (I haven't tested); `system('rm -f -r dir')`

Comment: i am on octave @Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `confirm_recursive_rmdir` you can turn this question on or off. This is a feature of octave, matlab never asks to confirm `rmdir`

Comment: @Daniel.. rmdir('TEST','s'); How can I use confirm_recursive_rmdir.

Answer (score 0):

`confirm_recursive_rmdir(0)` will do the trick

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.